# Statistics and programming

Tags: python, numpy

I want to use any python statistical package to retrieve critical values of the normal PPCC distribution. How can I access these critical values if they are available ..for example in numpy or statlib. Let's say I have 5 samples and I want to retrieve the critical value at p 0.05. I have the table already from this website (http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/eda3676.htm) but I would like to know if this table is available in python and how to use. 
Thank you. (be kind I'm a novice programmer)

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.shapiro.html mentions three alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a table like that. However, you can use that table in code like this.

```
def normal_ppcc(x, n, level):
    table = {3: [0.8687, 0.879], 4: [0.8234, 0.8666], 5: [0.824, 0.8786], 6: [0.8351, 0.888], 7: [0.8474, 0.897], 8: [0.859, 0.9043], 9: [0.8689, 0.9115], 10: [0.8765, 0.9173], 11: [0.8838, 0.9223], 12: [0.8918, 0.9267], 13: [0.8974, 0.931], 14: [0.9029, 0.9343], 15: [0.908, 0.9376], 16: [0.9121, 0.9405], 17: [0.916, 0.9433], 18: [0.9196, 0.9452], 19: [0.923, 0.9479], 20: [0.9256, 0.9498]}
    if not n in table:
        raise ValueError ('n not in table')
    if not level in [0.01, 0.05]:
        raise ValueError ('invalid level')
    entry = 0 if level == 0.01 else 1
    return x < table[n][entry]

print (normal_ppcc(0.985, 10, 0.05))
print (normal_ppcc(0.8764, 10, 0.01))
print (normal_ppcc(0.9172, 10, 0.05))
print (normal_ppcc(0.92, 10, 0.05))
```

To create the table I copy-pasted the table into a fresh editor window and then ran this Python code. Then I copy-pasted the output into the code above.

```
lines = '''\
3        0.8687        0.8790
4        0.8234        0.8666
5        0.8240        0.8786
6        0.8351        0.8880
7        0.8474        0.8970
8        0.8590        0.9043
9        0.8689        0.9115
10        0.8765        0.9173
11        0.8838        0.9223
12        0.8918        0.9267
13        0.8974        0.9310
14        0.9029        0.9343
15        0.9080        0.9376
16        0.9121        0.9405
17        0.9160        0.9433
18        0.9196        0.9452
19        0.9230        0.9479
20        0.9256        0.9498'''

table = {}
for line in lines.split('\n'):
    n, x_01, x_05 = line.split()
    table[int(n)] = [float(x_01), float(x_05)]
print (table)
```

Comment: Thank you @BillBell. I was hoping the table is in a statistics package already. I guess this will have to do.

Comment: Thank you @Bill Bell. I was hoping the critical values are available in any of the python statistics packages. I guess this will have to do.